# Scrapy как парсить внутренюю ссылку?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-scraping

Недавно начал изучать scrapy. На главной странице изображены товары и информация о них, цена товара загружается позже. При переходе на страницу товара цена загружается сразу. Необходимо со страницы списка товаров перейти на страницу товара и запарсить цену. Как это можно сделать?

```
class DnsUltrabookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dns_ultrabook'
    allowed_domains = ['dns-shop.ru']
    start_urls = ['https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a892f816404e77/?f[65c]=264d&p=1']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Give data of css
        product_name = response.css('.product-info__title-link > a::text').extract()
        product_info = response.css('.product-info__title-description::text').extract()
        product_url = response.css('.product-info__title-link > a::attr(href)').extract()
        full_product_url = []
        for url in product_url:
            full_product_url.append("https://www.dns-shop.ru" + url)
        row_data = zip(product_name, full_product_url, product_info)

        for item in row_data:
            # Create dictionary
            scraped_info = {
                'page': response.url,
                'product_name': item[0],
                'product_url': item[1],
                'info': item[2],
            }

            # Generate Information for scraping
            yield scraped_info
```

Видел возможность такого делать через `scrapy.Response(url=url)`, но данная функция возвращает только запрос, а не ответ.
Вот пример того как можно получить информацию о цене со страницы товара: `response.css(".current-price-value::attr(data-price-value)").extract_first()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class DnsUltrabookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dns_ultrabook'
    allowed_domains = ['dns-shop.ru']
    start_urls = ['https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a892f816404e77/?f[65c]=264d&p=1']


    def parse(self, response):
        # Give data of css
        product_name = response.css('.product-info__title-link > a::text').extract()
        product_info = response.css('.product-info__title-description::text').extract()
        product_url = response.css('.product-info__title-link > a::attr(href)').extract()
        full_product_url = []
        for url in product_url:
            full_product_url.append("https://www.dns-shop.ru" + url)
        for i in range(len(full_product_url)):
            yield scrapy.Request(full_product_url[i], callback=self.price_parse,
                                 meta={'product_name': product_name[i],
                                       'product_info': product_info[i],
                                       'product_url': full_product_url[i]})


    def price_parse(self, response):
        price = response.xpath('//span[@class="current-price-value"]//text()').extract_first()
        scrap_info = {
            'product_name': response.meta['product_name'],
            'product_info': response.meta['product_info'],
            'product_url': response.meta['product_url'],
            'price': price
        }
        return scrap_info
```